# how to correctly setup the html spell check for another language?

Tags: html, contenteditable, spell-checking

i already set html lang attr to another language i want, but still the spell check only recognize english.

```
<html lang="id">
```

the language i want is bahasa indonesia like the code above, but still, the spell check doesn't work correcly and still use english as it primary. see the picture belom for the result.
[image: spell check doesn't recognize bahasa indonesia lang]

as you can see, the picture above use english as spell check language, and doesn't recognize bahasa indonesia even though i set is as it primiary language(see the code above).

note: the h1 on the picture is in contentEditable main element like code below

```
<main contentEditable="true">
  <h1>hello apa kabar</h1>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the current documentation, it can be done but using help from javascript to control the output.

```
<html lang="id">
 <body>
  <main contentEditable="true">
   <h1 lang="id">hello apa kabar</h1>
   <h1 lang="en">Hello how are you</h1>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can detect the language, then with the help from javascript to show or hide the respective div based on the detected language.

Comment: hello fadli, thank you for the answer. I have tried that, and it's doesn't work

Comment: I will try to add the javascript part